# Using the next_day to retrieve the previous day and the following day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a sql code. I am trying to retrieve the previous Monday and next Sunday using the next_Day function. How would I make the query work? I am currently using oracle sql developer to run my query.

This is the data I want to show:

```
 FullName,       Monday         Sunday
 John Brown      31-DEC-2012    06-JAN-2013
```

Here is my code I have so far:

```
 SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, DOB,
 Add_Months(dob, (extract(YEAR from sysdate)- extract(YEAR from dob))*12) AS BirthDateThisYear
 FROM Customers
```

I tried adding these statements, but I got an error after runninng the query:

```
  NEXT_DAY(BirthDateThisYear-8, 'MON') AS PreviousMonday
  NEXT_DAY((BirthDateThisYear-8)+6, 'MON') AS UpcomingSunday
```

Comment: the error i got was: ORA-00904: "BIRTHDATETHISYEAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 13

Answer (score 2):

I can try this:

```
select First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name as FullName,
       NEXT_DAY(BirthDateThisYear-8, 'Monday') AS PreviousMonday,
       NEXT_DAY(BirthDateThisYear-1, 'Sunday') AS UpcomingSunday
from       
(SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, DOB,
 Add_Months(dob, (extract(YEAR from sysdate)- extract(YEAR from dob))*12) AS BirthDateThisYear
 FROM Customers)
```

Comment: do you know what the subtracting 8 do in   NEXT_DAY((BirthDateThisYear-8)? it was in the book but it doesn't explain it clearly.

Comment: @Lisa Tse You want a previous monday. So you need date-7 (minus one week). But if your date is monday you'll get the same date (and you want the previous). That's why there is one extra day -7-1 = -8

Comment: @Lisa Tse To ensure that previous monday is not the same date

Comment: Ah i see, that makes sense! That was what I was thinking too. Thanks so much for the help!